# How to generate reports in PHP from sql server database.Can i use SQLserver reporting services from PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have databases in SQL server 2000 and i would like to attach to new SQL server 2008.
I'm using PHP 5.4.5 on windows server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.
I would like to generate static or dynamic reports for users to customize their printing.
Can i use SQLserver reporting services(SSRS) 2008 from PHP to generate reports.
i have heard of crystal report.but i would like to open source report software if SSRS cant be used. 
Also user should be able to export to file formats like Excel,PDF..
Any guidance or links in this regard will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for, it has everything you want. Just follow the code sample in the page
http://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/

You will need to enable Basic Authentication on your SSRS server to get it to work.